# Is it true that SERE's in the army are given a dog to raise to kill them?

Tags: dogs

My daughter told me that her fiance was in the SERE's in the army and that he was given a puppy to raise and then had to shoot it so he would learn to not become attached?  He is stating that the dog she has reminds him of the dog he had to shoot so therefore the dog isn't allowed in the house and the fiancé has no contact with the dog.

Is this really true about having to kill a dog or is he making this up?

Comment: What's a SERE please?

Comment: "SERE" apparently stands for "Survival, Evasion, Resistance, and Escape", but it's not a single program but a genre of military and private programs.  Therefore it's unlikely that there's a single standard, especially one that would attract so much ire from ASPCA et al.

Comment: @DanielRHicks well, SERE programs did have [some problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival,_Evasion,_Resistance_and_Escape#Controversies) with their curricula in the past. Nothing dog-related, though. The claim seems more like something taken out of some movie plot.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov in fact it's lifted straight from the movie [Kingsman: The Secret Service](http://screenprism.com/insights/article/why-were-the-agents-in-kingsman-asked-to-shoot-a-dog-as-their-final-trainin)

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant: ...which makes the claim by OP daughter's fiancee doubly dubious. "In the SERE's"? That's mightily unspecific, especially since we don't even have a country specified. When I served in the German army, we were told quite specifically what that training entailed, as it was (at the time) compulsory for officers. I am pretty sure we would have heard of any dog killing.

Comment: I don't believe it. There is something a bit off if the OP's daughter's fiance isn't allowed in daughter's house because she is frightened of him and who has been taught not to become attached. Is this a [marriage of convenience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_of_convenience) then? Will she she have to get rid of the dog when he moves in or will he do it for her?

Comment: What does OP mean?  @weathervane I think you misunderstood my question. My daughter isn’t afraid of her fiancé. He lives with her. What I was asking is if it is true that a SERE is given a dog to train to have to turn around and kill it so to desensitize them?  She has a dog that has to stay outside because he says it reminds him of the dog he had to kill after training it.

Comment: OP means Original Poster who asked the question. You can always edit the question to make it clear who isn't allowed in the house.

Comment: Thank you @weathervane. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are welcome, but the fiance sounds like a control freak. Who banned the dog? Was the story made up by the fiance to get rid of the dog? Keep the dog and ban the fiance, although a control freak isn't going to make it easy.

Comment: He banned the dog. I am now thinking that the story was made up to get rid of the dog.

Comment: Been there (SoCal) and JEST (PI). Her fiancee told her a sea story.No one is there long enough to raise a puppy or anything else besides blisters.

Answer (score 1):

[USAF SERE Training Manual](https://fas.org/irp/doddir/usaf/afh10-644.pdf)

There is a section in the USAF's training manual about how to elude tracking dogs, but nothing else. There's also a section on emotional well being, but nothing that appears to relate to avoiding emotional attachments.

More or less, SERE is wilderness survival training, techniques to assist search and rescue and avoiding detection.  It's a part of special forces training, but is also taught to anyone that may be operating in a forward area (pilots, medical personnel, etc).  It's not something that's limited to special forces personnel.